# Why does $\text{dim } \text{null} A = 1$ lead to the fact that solutions of $Ax=b$ are multiples of a nonzero solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

I’m reading a textbook about linear algebra and there is a solved question that in some point came to $\text{dim } \text{null} A = 1$ and conclude that solutions of $Ax=b$ are multiple of a nonezero solution.

And in another one $\text{dim } \text{null} A = 2$ leads to the conclusion that there is no nonzero solution for $Ax=b$ that we can write other than solutions as a multiple of it.

The question is

Suppose a nonhomogeneous system of nine linear equations in ten unknowns has a solution for all possible constants on the right side of the equation. Is it possible to find two nonzero solutions of the associated homogeneous system that are not multiples of each other?

The answer

When $Ax=b$ has a solution for every $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then we conclude every row of the matrix has pivot positions, so $\text{dim } \text{row} A = \text{rank} A = 9$. According to a theorem we know, for every $m \times n$ matrix $\text{rank} A + \text{dim } \text{null} A = n$, so here $\text{dim } \text{null} A = 10 - 9 = 1$. The author then concludes that we cant find two solutions that are not multiple of each other.

Why is it that we can conclude this? How can we conclude this? (Using theorem or direct intuition is equally good).

Thank you guys

Comment: Are you talking about 3 dimensional systems here?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan not necessarily. I know a theorem that states $Rank A + dim Null A=n$ for anu m*n matrix A. So as i said , not necessarily.

Comment: I think maybe you've read them out of context.. could you provide more context?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan please check the question again.I edited it

Answer (score 1):

You have a system such that $A \in R_{9,10}, x\in R^{10}, b \in R^{9}$

Now, if the system has a solution for every $b$, we can interpret this as there always is a way to express $b$ as a linear combination of the columns of the matrix $A$. Since this is true for any $b$, the columns of matrix $A$ must span the vector space of $b$, that is $R^9$

If we write $A$ as

$$A = [v_1 \space v_2 \space v_3 \space ... \space v_{10}]$$

Then we have a basis of $R^9$ among these 10 vectors, hence 9 are linearly independent (this is interpreted as having rank = 9)

WLOG, we can assume that these independent vectors are $v_1$ to $v_9$. Hence, we can express $v_{10}$ as follows

$$v_{10} = \sum_1^9\lambda_iv_i$$

Now, consider the homogeneous system $Ax = 0$.The solutions to thise all belong to the null space of $A$ from the definiton of the null space. Using the rank-nullity theorem, we have that the nullity is 1. Therefore, all vectors in this space can be written as a scalar time some base vector - hence all solutions are scalar multiples of each other